# Announcing chat sessions!

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently proposed about doing a chat session in Biology chat and most people agreed with [MattDMo's answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3266/10401). I am going to use these suggestions to decide how to make our first chat sessions work.

**Topic**

There will be no formal topic but if nobody has anything interesting to talk about, I have decided we could talk about CRISPR or related, and phylogenetics.

We can chat about our lives, work (or college), questions on the main site, and biology of course! Please do not discuss controversial topics like politics.

If it gets out of hand, I will call a mod for you to be suspended (unless a mod is already there) and may even flag the message (calling *all* moderators on SE) should the issue be serious enough.

**How long**

8 hours (plus or minus 2 hours). Of course, you do not need to be there for the entire period.

**When**

This is the main question. When do you want our chat sessions to be? I will have possible times as answers to this question and you vote for the ones you can make. If you have a better time that works for you that isn't part of the answers I already have, please feel free to write an answer. The first chat session will be two weeks from now.

**Moderation**

First of all, I am not a mod. But I will try to regulate the event. The regular mods will hopefully be there, especially when I am not available.

**Bot idea?**

I plan to perhaps introduce an SE chat bot that asks if somebody wants to participate in the chat session and asks the use to introduce himself/herself if (s)he is attending for the first time. If you like this idea and want to give feedback, please write an answer.

Comment: **8 hours?** That . . . might not work.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. this is based on MattDMo's suggestion. If others agree with MAR (by upvoting the comment) I will change the times to vote.

Comment: @All: If you are not feeling comfortable with upvoting any of the answers below, but still would like to participate in an event; post another answer containing the timezone you'd like so others can vote.

Answer (score 2):

## Vote for time - Monday February 8th 10:00 to 18:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

## Vote for time - Tuesday February 9 10:00 -18:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

## Vote for time - Wednesday February 10 10:00 -18:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

## Vote for time - Thursday February 11 10:00 -18:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

## Vote for time - Friday February 12 10:00 -18:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Monday February 8th 0:00 UTC to 8:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Tuesday February 9 0:00 UTC - 8:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Wednesday February 10 0:00 to 8:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Thursday February 11 0:00 UTC to 8:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Friday February 12th 0:00 UTC to 8:00 UTC

(Probably best for me)

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time - Saturday February 13 0:00 to 8:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

## Vote for time Saturday February 13 10:00 to 18:00 UTC